# Project data doesn't updates / Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, geojson

I'm using Mapbox editor (https://www.mapbox.com/editor) for editing my maps.
But after first save, only Editor view updates with new data. 
So, I'm adding new markers and press Save and see changes on the screen.

But my embeded map doesn't have new updates. 
I've also checked 'markers.geojson' and Share link, both have only first time saved data.

I've checked diff preferences but can't find anything related to this issue...

Comment: I'm wondering if you got this solved - I have similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got response from Mapbox:

> "Between the time that you edit data on your maps and when the GeoJSON
>   public representation (your markers) updates, there's a delay of up to
>   an hour. Hope this helps and let me know if you have questions."

Yes, looks like it updates with delay or how i suppose rather ones per hour.